# open a website and refresh it as per the time using spyder (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

My code is here I want to open a youtube link and it will get refresh after 10 seconds here my code but it cant execute please help me :

```
import os 
import time 
import webbrowser

cycles=12 
num=3 
delay=0.10 
chromedir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s' 
website = input("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY") 
hits=cycles*num
print("You will access " +website+ " " , hits, " times")

for i in range(cycles): 
    for i in range(0,num): 
        webbrowser.get(chromedir).open(website)
        time.sleep(delay) 
        os.system("tskill /A iexplore") 
        os.system("tskill /A Chrome")
```

Comment: Your "code" does not look like Python code to me. Please bother to format it.

Comment: This is a python code which is executed in spyder

Comment: No Python interpreter will ever execute the first line. You _must_ format your code. Posting garbage like that is totally disrespectful.

Comment: I think Selenium will solve the problem

Comment: Either use selenium webdriver, or pyautogui to do the cmd-r/ctrl-r keystroke

Comment: Here is the documentation for it: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: For refreshing `driver.refresh()`

Comment: And use `WebDriverWait` to wait n time

Comment: Could you please make a correct code for me so i can run it on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `selenium`. Here for installing: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
chromedir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
driver = wd.Chrome(chromedir)
website = input("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY") 
driver.open(website)
def until_func(driver):
    driver.refresh()
orderElem = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=60, poll_frequency=10).until(until_func)
```